# Python - Getting Started

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am just getting started with Python and wrote a simple perimeter program. However whenever I type python perimeter.py in my terminal I get the following error I don't know how to solve it.

```
>>> python perimeter.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python perimeter.py
               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is that problem? How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You type `python perimeter.py` in your command shell to start the Python interpreter. You don't type it *in* the Python interpreter.

If you really need to run the script from within the Python interpreter, do `execfile('perimeter.py')`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: If you remove the `.py`, that may work the first time, but not any subsequent times.

Comment: Ah, whoops. `import perimeter`